# Using the Windows command line, remove unwanted prefixes

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, command, findstr

I have a number of files that need to be renamed without their current prefix. Unfortunately there is no strict format

```
01 - MYFILE.txt
02 - MYFILE - Maybe with extra hypen.mp3
333 - MYFILE.bin
```

These should be renamed to:

```
MYFILE.txt
MYFILE - Maybe with extra hypen.mp3
MYFILE.bin
```

Basically I want to remove any characters in class [0-9- ] i.e. any hypen, digit, space UNTIL a character is found that is not in this class.

I need to get this done using a batch file

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET sourcedir=u:\test
FOR %%o IN ("%sourcedir%\*") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=*delims=0123456789- " %%a IN ("%%~nxo") DO (
  ECHO REN "%%o" "%%a"
  IF /i NOT "%%~nxo"=="%%a" ECHO gated REN "%%o" "%%a"
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

The required commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Sample source dir listing:

```
 Directory of u:\test

06/01/2014  08:36                 0 01 - myfile.txt
06/01/2014  08:37                 0 02 - myfile - maybe with extra hypen.mp3
06/01/2014  08:38                 0 333 - myfile.bin
06/01/2014  08:38                 0 leave me alone - I am not to change.atall
```

And results:

```
REN "u:\test\01 - myfile.txt" "myfile.txt"
REN "u:\test\02 - myfile - maybe with extra hypen.mp3" "myfile - maybe with extra hypen.mp3"
REN "u:\test\333 - myfile.bin" "myfile.bin"
REN "u:\test\leave me alone - I am not to change.atall" "leave me alone - I am not to change.atall"
```

---

edit - new `gated` rename line echoed to bypass attempts to rename to same name.

Comment: Not being too accustomed with the various for commands, I had not thought of the nested for loops. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

This is not to hard to accomplish using the DOS for/f command.

Assume you have a file named test.txt:

```
01 - MYFILE.txt
02 - MYFILE - Maybe with extra hypen.mp3
333 - MYFILE.bin
```

Here is a batch file that may be helpful. named test.bat in my case:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=0123456789- " %%i in (test.txt) do @echo %%i %%j %%k
set /p DUMMY=Hit ENTER to continue...
```

Here is the results in a cmd window:

```
C:\Users\Ron Fredericks\Desktop>FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=0123456789- " %i in (
test.txt) do @echo %i %j %k
MYFILE.txt
MYFILE Maybe with extra hypen.mp3
MYFILE.bin

C:\Users\Ron Fredericks\Desktop>set /p DUMMY=Hit ENTER to continue...
Hit ENTER to continue...
```

Comment: Instead of relying on a text file that can become outdated - why not change your for loop to - `FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=0123456789- " %%i in ('dir /B directory\to\check') do @echo %%i %%j %%k`